# What is meant by Readymade Framework?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Can you help me with what is meant by readymade framework?I have to build an HTML page using readymade framework. Does it mean using tools such as Wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readymade framework means it includes all (CSS, JavaScript) class, HTML Components, some inbuilt JavaScript options like (popup, accordion, slider...) so that you can it use easily and also it includes a responsive grid it will work on desktop as well as on devices.

Some HTML Framework link:

http://getbootstrap.com/

http://foundation.zurb.com/

WordPress is content management system (CMS) so the user can insert, update and delete the content but HTML framework is only for the frontend.

Thanks,

Ashish Bhalerao :)

Answer (score -1):

I would think this would be something like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) (A framework to create the front end of a website quickly and responsively).

Answer (score -1):

Which framework are you talking about?

Serverside framework like Zend or Wordpress will provide you heaps of functionality ready for you to use like user management, form validation etc.
Clientside framework like Bootstrap or Stylus will provide you with design components for your HTML code.
A javascript framework like ReactJS or angular (technically also clientside) will provide you with extra functionality or cross browser implementation of common functions.

In your case I would assume you are required to use a clientside framework so you don't have to create all the components of the design yourself.

Common frameworks are:

- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
- [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/)
- [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/)

and many others...

Comment: I have got a psd webpage designed. I want to build it to an HTML page which is also responsive on other devices. So it is a client side framework right?